# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Controller (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I try to submit a form for a proposal.  The form consists of choosing a model from a collection of countries and entering in a few text boxes.  However, when I go to select the country, Rails says it is getting a string when it expects a country.

Proposal model:

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :my_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
    belongs_to :country, class_name: "Country", foreign_key: "country_id"
    after_initialize :set_defaults

    validates :status, presence: true
    validates :country, presence: true
    validates :q1, length: {maximum: 250}
    validates :q2, length: {maximum: 250}
    .
    .
    .
    validates :q30, length: {maximum: 250}

    def set_defaults
        self.status = "Pending"
    end
end
```

Proposal controller:

```
class ProposalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  def index
    @proposals = Proposal.all
  end

  def new
    @proposal = Proposal.new
  end

  def create
    @proposal = Proposal.new(params.require(:proposal).permit(:status, :country,  
    :q1, 
    :q2,
    .
    .
    .
    :q30))
    @proposal.save!
    redirect_to home_path
  end

  def display
    @proposal = Proposal.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

View:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-left">

       <%= form_for(@proposal) do |f| %>
          <%= f.collection_select(:country, Country.all.order('name'), :id, :name) %>
          <br><p><%= f.submit %></p><br>
       <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Migration:

```
class CreateProposals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :proposals do |t|
      t.string :status, :default => "Pending"
      t.integer :country_id
      t.text :q1 
      t.text :q2 
      .
      .
      .
      t.text :q30

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `country` to `country_id` in `create` method

```
def create
  @proposal = Proposal.new(params.require(:proposal).permit(:status, :country_id,
  :q1, 
  :q2,
  .
  .        .
  :q30))
  @proposal.save!
  redirect_to home_path
end
```

Comment: I edited method to permit(:country_id) but now I get an error saying "Validation failed: Country can't be blank"

Comment: @BerryAllen Try changing `validates :country, presence: true` to `validates :country_id, presence: true` in proposal model.

Comment: Undefined method for 'country_id' for Proposal.  Same after adding column in migration file.

Comment: @BerryAllen Thats not right. Create another migration file to add `country_id` to `proposals` and do `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: All changes + new migration = "Validation failed. Country can't be blank"

Comment: @BerryAllen Why you changed it `<%= f.collection_select(:country, Country.all.order('name'), :id, :name) %>` revert back to initial i.e, `country_id` instead of `country`

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! It is working now. I think it was because I needed that extra migration to add country_id to Proposal table.  Before, it was saying there was no method for 'country_id'

Comment: @BerryAllen Good. Accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One think that I see is wrong in your example is that you permit :country instead of :country_id that you send from form. Let me know if that helped.

```
@proposal = Proposal.new(params.require(:proposal).permit(:status, :country_id, ...
```